# Access-Control-Max-Age vs Cache-Control

Tags: http-headers

What is the difference between Access-Control-Max-Age and Cache-Control within a http response header?

```
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Cache-Control:max-age=21600, public
```

I have the feeling that they do not refer to the same thing, as often they appear together and sometimes with different values.

If they *do* both appear within a http header, but contain different values, would this be valid?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> What is the difference between Access-Control-Max-Age and Cache-Control within a http response header?

These headers are used in different contexts and for different purposes:

- [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) is used in a wide general context, to specify the maximum amount of time a resource will be considered fresh.
- [`Access-Control-Max-Age`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age) is used in [CORS preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/preflight_request). It indicates how long the results of a preflight request can be cached. The results in this case is the content of the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers.

In other words, these values concern the freshness of different things.
`Cache-Control`'s `max-age=` is for the resource downloaded,
`Access-Control-Max-Age` is for content in other header fields.

> I have the feeling that they do not refer to the same thing, as often they appear together and sometimes with different values.

As explained earlier, they refer to completely different things.
Seeing them together is probably just coincidence.
Setting `Cache-Control`'s `max-age` is generally recommended when applicable.
Setting `Access-Control-Max-Age` doesn't seem terribly important,
as browsers likely set sensible default values.

> If they do both appear within a http header, but contain different values, would this be valid?

As these headers are unrelated,
this is valid.
However, the value `Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000` in your example is a bit strange,
as browsers typically limit this to much smaller values
(Firefox caps this at 24 hours (86400 seconds) and Chromium at 10 minutes (600 seconds)). Chromium also specifies a default value of 5 seconds.

Addendum by [@Filippos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291118/filippos):

> Also note that Access-Control-Max-Age can only be used (meaningfully) in preflight requests, that employ HTTP OPTIONS. At the same time HTTP spec (RFC 7231) does not permit caching in HTTP OPTIONS request ("Responses to the OPTIONS method are not cacheable"), so in essence, for HTTP OPTIONS, you are left only with Access-Control-Max-Age

Comment: That makes sense, there may be some cross domain resources being hosted on the example domain, but the Access-Control headers are appearing (incorrectly) on every http response rather than the resource in question. Being out of context it threw me as I wasn't expecting the Access-Control header to appear on standard non-shared resources. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Also note that Access-Control-Max-Age can only be used (meaningfully) in preflight requests, that employ HTTP OPTIONS. At the same time HTTP spec (RFC 7231) does not permit caching in HTTP OPTIONS request ("Responses to the OPTIONS method are not cacheable"), so in essence, for HTTP OPTIONS, you are left only with Access-Control-Max-Age.